# AJAX save works with button but not image

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have an AJAX submitted form using the following

```
$('#savelink').click(function(){
$("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
$.ajax({
    url: 'linktextadd.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: "content="+$("input[id=linktext]").val(),
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(jqXHR+" || " + textStatus+" || " +errorThrown)
    }
  });
```

})

It works fine if I use a standard for button

```
<input id='savelink' type="button" value="Save" />
```

but if I try to pretty things up with an image

```
<input id='savelink' type="image" src="images/large-save.png" alt="Save" value="Save"  title="Save" />
```

it throws an error (textstatus) "error" - helpful :P

It looks like it isn't even getting to the PHP page as a mail() flag in there isn't being triggered

If I change the type of the same input code to button it works again

```
<input id='savelink' type="button" src="images/large-save.png" alt="Save" value="Save"  title="Save" />
```

but of course I lose the pretty.

Ideas?

**[SOLUTION]**  Just to make it clear, here is the solution

```
$('#savelink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the type of an input to `image`, the button will then act as a `submit` button.  That means there is a submit event that you need to suppress.

```
$('#savelink').click(function(evnt){
   evnt.preventDefault();
   ...
```

Comment: thanks again, just doing the .click(e) works fine.  But through your answer and then update I have learned something - and that is always good

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<button>`

```
<button id="savelink"><img src="images/large-save.png" alt="Save"></button>
```

Comment: He will have the exact same issue, button also comes with a submit event which is the problem...